# mysql count from left join with additional conditions

Tags: mysql

I have to generate task report of 50 employees. So
Lets consider the two tables with following columns

employees: `id|name`

employee_tasks: `id|employee_id|task_description|status|date`

there are two types of status `[1 = incomplete, 2 = completed]`

An Employee may or may not have tasks.

So for a given date i want to list all 50 employees with their tasks as follows.

```
--------------------------------------
id | employee | completed | incomplete
--------------------------------------
1  | Mr. X    | 4         | 3    
2  | Mr. Y    | 0         | 0
```

So I wrote the queries as

```
select e.id, e.name as employee,
       sum(case when status=2 then 1 else 0 end) as completed,
       sum(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as incomplete
from employees e
         left join employee_tasks et on et.employee_id=e.id
where (et.date=GIVEN_DATE or et.date is null)
group by e.id
```

In the result set I see variations of employee count. It should be 50 always. But for different different date the result set is contains sometimes 42 or 47 employees. Cant seem to understand why.

***(used (et.date is null) because employee may not have any tasks for the given date)***

Comment: Please post sample data, current result and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some employees are filtered out in the result, the `where` clause is likely suspect. What might work is moving the filtering to the `join`.

```sql
select e.id, e.name as employee,
       sum(case when status=2 then 1 else 0 end) as completed,
       sum(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as incomplete
from employees e
left join employee_tasks et on et.employee_id=e.id and et.date=GIVEN_DATE
group by e.id
```